# Spring Boot 1.3 testing with mocking nested Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am trying to write an integration test that tests class A that has nested dependency injection.  So I ultimately I want to inject mock of class C.

I am aware of the annotation @MockBean that is available from Spring Boot 1.4 but my hard requirement is Spring Boot 1.3 with Java 7.
Could someone help me how I can mock nested dependency?

```
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;

    private void run() {
        b.run();
    }
}

public class B {
    @Autowired
    private C c;

    private void run() {
        c.run();
    }
}

public class C {
    private void run() {
        //some action
    }
}

public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Test
    private void runTest() {
        a.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Mock bean of the same type in the Test context and mark it as Primary.

Comment: Could you be able to show me like an example code? I am relatively new to Spring and the spring context is kinda foggy for me

Answer (score 0):

Since the [`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/) has been released as of the Spring version `1.4`, the best alternative you might use is the [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) library and its mocking features instead:

```
C c = Mockito.mock(C.class);
```

Prefer the constructor injection instead of the setters one. You can pass this mocked class through the constructor.

---

Alternatively, there is a possibility to use [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) to distinguish a real bean from the mocked one. Read more at [Injecting Mockito Mocks into Spring Beans](https://www.baeldung.com/injecting-mocks-in-spring).

Comment: Of course. Recomendation is constructor injecjtion for easy testing and easier setup of beans spring test. To write less boilerplate code use lombok with @AllArgConstructor.

Comment: Additonally check `@Mock (answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)`. This make it easy to setup mock answers with deep stubs.